Extracting Amazon Images URL from Product Detail Page using Python, Selenium
I want to extract all the images associated with a product from Amazon. Suppose the product has 8 media files associated with it. I want to extract the image url i.e., the src atrributed associated with it. I am using Python to do this. The approach is to use the main div which contains media of the product (specified by id = main-image-container) and then extract whatever img src can be found inside the class= imgTagWrapper. The title is in the csv file.
This is the code I am currently using:
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

def setup_driver():
    """Setup Chrome WebDriver with options."""
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True  # Optional: Run in headless mode if no browser UI needed
    service = Service(executable_path=r'C:\Users\preri\Desktop\Yorkee\chromedriver.exe')
    return webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

def fetch_images(title, driver):
    """Fetch image URLs for a given product title from Amazon within 'imgTagWrapper'."""
    try:
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.in")
        search_box = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "field-keywords")
        search_box.send_keys(title + Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(5)  # Allow time for search results to load

        # Wait for product links to be visible and interactable
        product_links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.a-link-normal.s-link-style'))
        )

        if product_links:
            product_links[0].click()  # Click the first product link if available
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main-image-container"))
            )
            # Specific fetch within 'imgTagWrapper'
            images = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#main-image-container .imgTagWrapper img')
            return [img.get_attribute('src') for img in images if img.get_attribute('src')]
        else:
            print(f"No product links found for {title}")
            return []
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching images for {title}: {e}")
        return []
    finally:
        driver.quit()

def main():
    driver = setup_driver()
    df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\preri\Desktop\Yorkee\Yorkee Sample Prod.csv')
    df['Title'] = df['Title'].astype(str)  # Convert all titles to string
    df['Image URLs'] = df['Title'].apply(lambda title: fetch_images(title, driver))
    
    df.to_csv('modified_file_with_images.csv', index=False)
    print("All entries processed and saved.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I am getting this error:
Error fetching images for Anandlib Na Sahi Sahil To Hai: Message: 
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF755EA1502+60802]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF755E1AC02]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF755CD7CE4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF755D26D4D]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF755D26E1C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF755D6CE37]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF755D4ABBF]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF755D6A224]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF755D4A923]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF755D18FEC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF755D19C21]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7561A411D+3217821]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7561E60B7+3488055]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7561DF03F+3459263]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF755F5B846+823494]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF755E25F9F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF755E20EC4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF755E21052]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF755E118A4]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF98A42257D+29]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF98B34AA48+40]

All entries processed and saved.
What am I doing wrong?
I tried using UIPath before this, couldn't figure it out so switched to Python.

Better to ask about the specific technical issue (call X causes stack trace Y under circumstance Z) than to ask about scraping Amazon in general -- we want our answers to be things that remain useful indefinitely, and any answer about scraping a specific page only remains useful until the content of that page changes (or the people behind it introduce new countermeasures to prevent scraping, or so forth)

I am sorry, I haven't interacted with stack overflow that much, will keep this in mind from hereon. Would really appreciate if I could get help on this..@CharlesDuffy

Remove the try-except so you can see the actually error message. Once you get that, then investigate what the issue is. If you can't figure it out on your own, come back and edit your question and add the full error message as text, properly formatted.

Wrapping your entire script in a try-except may seem like a good idea but what it does in the end is hide all the actual errors meaning you can't figure out what actually went wrong. In general, I would only use a try-except around the specific lines of code where I was potentially expecting an error. Also don't just catch all Exception types... that's going to trap every single error type. Just catch what you plan to handle and let the rest get through so you can see the errors.

Hey @JeffC, thanks alot for the advise. I would do this and proceed to try to figure out. I have just started to try to code and this for me is a great insight. Appreciate it! Thank you!
